# why my reducer won't update the state ? -Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

i'm trying to remove an item from array with filter method. i see `ItemRemoved` in Redux Dev Tools but nothing happen in state.
Why is this happening?
i will really appreciate some help. this is driving me crazy

```js
import { createSlice, createAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
// Action Creater
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "shoppingCart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    itemAdded: some code // ,
    itemRemoved: (cart, { payload }) => {
      cart.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.id === payload.id) {
          if (item.count === 1) {


            return cart.filter((item) => item.id !== payload.id);
            // THIS RETURN IS NOT WORKING. 


          } else {
            const itemIndex = cart.indexOf(item);
            cart[itemIndex].count = cart[itemIndex].count - 1;
            return cart;
          }
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
export const { itemAdded, itemRemoved } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` inside `forEach` is not returning to `itemRemoved`. The `return` line is only finishing the function inside forEach. You can save the result in another variable and `return` after `foreach`. Maybe like this:

```js
let updatedCart;
cart.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.id === payload.id) {
        if (item.count === 1) {
            updatedCart = cart.filter((item) => item.id !== payload.id);
        } else {
            const itemIndex = cart.indexOf(item);
            cart[itemIndex].count = cart[itemIndex].count - 1;
            updatedCart = cart;
        }
    }
});

return updatedCart;
```

But if you don't need to iterate all elements in cart and if you return before checking all items, it would be more efficient to use something else other than `forEach`. Maybe like this:

```js
const itemIndex = cart.findIndex(item => item.id === payload.id);

if (itemIndex === -1)
    return cart;

if (cart[itemIndex].count == 1) {
    cart.splice(itemIndex, 1);
} else {
    cart[itemIndex].count--;
}
return cart;
```